# Не проигрывается одна из анимаций на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Когда нажимаю на кнопку удара, не проигрывается анимация Punch(), ее запускает State Punch.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public int directionInput;
public float jumpForce;
Rigidbody2D rb;
public bool isGrounded;
public GameObject sprite;
Animator anim;


private CharState State
{
    get { return (CharState)anim.GetInteger("State"); }
    set { anim.SetInteger("State", (int)value); }
}

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = sprite.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Start () {

}
private void Update()
{
    if (!isGrounded) State = CharState.Jump;
    if ((isGrounded) && (directionInput == 0))
    {
        State = CharState.Idle;
    }
    {
        if (directionInput < 0)
        {
            HoldLeft();
        }
        else if (directionInput > 0)
        {
            HoldRight();
        }
        else if (directionInput == 0) State = CharState.Idle;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * directionInput, rb.velocity.y);
}


public void Move(int InputAxis)
{
    directionInput = InputAxis;
}


public void HoldRight()
{
    sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
    State = CharState.Hold;
}


public void HoldLeft()
{ 
        sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        State = CharState.Hold;

}

public void Punch()
{
        State = CharState.Punch;
}

public void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    State = CharState.Jump;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
     if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}




public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Hold,
    Run,
    Jump,
    Punch
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала было бы неплохо увидеть автомат вашего аниматора.

Comment: От Anystate идет транзишены по одной стрелке: Anystate-Idle, Anystate-Jump, Anystate-Punch и т.д.

Comment: Скриншотом, пожалуйста. Вчитываться не особо удобно, особенно в "и т.д.".

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: А где вы вообще в коде запускаете Punch()?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker не дописал оказывается, Event trigger-ами все кнопки запускаются, OnPointDown. Кнопки в виде UI Image.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос **всю** необходимую информацию, в текущем состоянии ответить на него невозможно.

Comment: У вас точно правильно настроен переход между анимациями? Вы  смотрели какое значение установлено в State после нажатия вами кнопки удара? И совпадает ли оно со значением необходимым для перехода в анимацию.

Comment: @M.Green да, походу я в коде налажал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что Punch запускается, но при следующем же кадре вызывается Update, и состояние перевыставляется на idle или hold.

Comment: Есть вариант как исправить в коде?

Comment: Ну если быстро, то поместите код апдейта в еще один if. Проверьте прежде всего, что не играется анимация удара. Или первой строчкой в апдейте if (State == CharState.Punch) return;